# What does ActionScript mean by 'antiAliasType' in the following context?:

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, air

```
    // When I Run The Following Two Lines, I Get The Error Shown Below
    var B:Button=new Button();
    var lineMetrics:TextLineMetrics=B.measureText('Hello World');
    //   TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter antiAliasType must be non-null.
```

From My Point Of View, As Useless Errors Go, This One Is Unsurpassed.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last post in this thread may help:
http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=148610

Comment: This worked.  I needed to first add it to the canvas (canvas.addChild), then update its width.  measureText will fail quite magnificently if called on a component that isn't already visible on the stage.

Comment: Or you could just create an addedToStage event handler